# How to organize ,repository and service in the dropwizard Application

Tags: dropwizard

I have a dropwizard application ,I am registering my resource something like below

```
@Override
    public void run(final BackendConfiguration configuration, final Environment environment) {

        try {
            Stripe.apiKey = configuration.getSTRIPE_SECRET_KEY(); // Initializing

            Datastore datastore = morphiaBundle.getDatastore();

            ProductEntityDAO dao = new ProductEntityDAO(datastore);
            CandidateEntityDao candidateEntityDao = new CandidateEntityDao(datastore);
            PaymentHistoryEntityDao paymenthistory = new PaymentHistoryEntityDao(datastore);
            PaymentFailedEntityDao paymentFailedEntityDao = new PaymentFailedEntityDao(datastore);
            
            
            environment.jersey().register(new StripeResource(dao, candidateEntityDao, paymenthistory, client,
                    configuration.getApi(), configuration.getApiToken(), configuration.getCurrency()));
            // Dependency injection
            environment.jersey().register(new AbstractBinder() {
                @Override
                public void configure() {
                    bindAsContract(PaymentHistoryEntityDao.class).in(Singleton.class);
                    bindAsContract(PaymentService.class).in(Singleton.class);
                }
            });

            final FilterRegistration.Dynamic cors = environment.servlets().addFilter("CORS", CrossOriginFilter.class);

            // Configure CORS parameters
            cors.setInitParameter("allowedOrigins", "*");
            cors.setInitParameter("allowedHeaders", "X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,Origin");
            cors.setInitParameter("allowedMethods", "OPTIONS,GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,HEAD");

            // Add URL mapping
            cors.addMappingForUrlPatterns(EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class), true, "/*");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception occurred");
        }

    }
}
```

When I am trying to have dependency injection in my StripeResource something like below

```
public class StripeResource {
    private ProductEntityDAO dao;
    private PaymentHistoryEntityDao paymentHistoryDao;
    private String API_KEY;
    private CandidateEntityDao candidateDao;
    private Client client;
    private String evaluationServiceApi;
    private String currency;
    @Inject
    private PaymentService service;
    public StripeResource(ProductEntityDAO dao, CandidateEntityDao candidateDao, PaymentHistoryEntityDao paymentHistoryDao, Client client, String evaluationServiceApi, String API_KEY,String currency) {
        this.client = client;
        this.evaluationServiceApi = evaluationServiceApi;
        this.dao = dao;
        this.candidateDao = candidateDao;
        this.API_KEY = API_KEY;
        this.paymentHistoryDao = paymentHistoryDao;
        this.currency=currency;

    }

@Inject
public StripeResource(PaymentService service)
{
  this.service=service;// always null may be this constructor is never called
}
    
    
    }
```

the service is always null ,I am looking for a technique to do dependency injection in this scenario

Also  dao injection to PaymentService is Also Not Working

```
@Inject
    public PaymentService(PaymentHistoryEntityDao dao){
        this.dao = dao; // this is null in the app too
        
    }
```

Comment: You need to let the container create the resource instance (register as a class). If you're going to instantiate the resource yourself, you will not get container injection. You are trying to do both. Choose one option and inject _ALL_ dependencies the same way.

Comment: But then ,how can I get the configuration variables in the resource?@PaulSamsotha

Comment: this is what dropwizard docs says-https://www.dropwizard.io/en/latest/manual/jdbi3.html The problem I am facing is ,dropwizard docs say that we can pass database object to resource file only ,but I am looking to separate the repsoitory ,dao and service layer something like what spring offers ,can you suggest me how to do something like that

Comment: In Spring, generally you let the container inject everything. And you develop in a layered structure; repo -> business -> web (one above the other). Repo gets injected into service and service gets injected into web. If you want to talk Spring, that's what you're talking about. What you are doing is totally different. Do you get what I am saying that you are trying to use two different injection methods? Just use _ONE_ and use it for _ALL_ dependencies. If you need to container inject the configuration: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50025855/2587435